# How to plot two colors in the one line by other columns value?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1.65, -0.05, 0],
                 [1.68, -0.01, 0],
                 [1.70, 0.01, 1],
                 [1.67, -0.02, 1],
                 [1.73 , 0.05,  1],
                 [1.67 , 0.01,  1],
                 [ 1.67, -0.02,   1],
                 [1.70 , 0.03,  0],
                 [ 1.66, -0.01,  0],
                 [ 1.69 ,-0.01 , 0]
                 ])
df.rename(columns={1: "diff", 2: "label"},inplace=True)
df['label']=df['label'].astype(str)
print(df)
       0   diff   label

0    1.65 -0.05     0
1    1.68 -0.01     0
2    1.70  0.01     1
3    1.67 -0.02     1
4    1.73  0.05     1
5    1.67  0.01     1
6    1.67 -0.02     1
7    1.70  0.03     0
8    1.66 -0.01     0
9    1.69 -0.01     0
```

I want to plot first columns and give it different color by 'label' column.

label=1 blue , label=0 red

That is , there are two colors in the one line.

I use the following code to plot.

```
df.iloc[0:2,0].plot(y=df.columns[0],color='r', )
df.iloc[1:7,0].plot(y=df.columns[0],color='b' )
df.iloc[6:10,0].plot(y=df.columns[0],color='r' )
```

Have any better method to plot?

In fact,the real data have 10000 rows

Comment: Search Stackoverflow or the web for solutions using a `LineCollection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are trying to plot the value of `0` by its interaction with the previous value in the dataset, relative to the index.

**My proposed solution is to plot each datapoint individually:**

```
# First, create a new column for color
df['color'] = df['label'].map({0:'red',1:'blue'})

# Next, import & set up subplot
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(10,4))

# Iterate through rows
for idx, row in df[[0,'color']].iterrows():
  v, c = row
  # If you want a scatter plot
  ax.scatter(idx, v, color=c)
  if idx>0:
    # If you want a line plot
    ax.plot([idx-1,idx], [prev_v, v], color=c)

  # Set the previous value
  prev_v = v

# Add a legend
red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='Losses')
blue_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='blue', label='Gains')

ax.legend(handles=[red_patch,blue_patch])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi,I found if I define prev_v before use prev_v,the plot only have scatter.
Why can use prev_v  before define it?

Comment: `prev v` is not defined until the first iteration of the loop is completed. (Hence `if idx>0`)

Comment: Consider accepting my answer if it solves your Q @disney82231

Answer (score 0):

You can probably simplify it but as a general solution the following lines should help you grab all of the rows where label is 1 or 0:

```
# label == 1
df.iloc[df['label'].where(df['label'].astype(int) == 1).dropna().index].plot(y=df.columns[0], color='b')
# label == 0
df.iloc[df['label'].where(df['label'].astype(int) == 0).dropna().index].plot(y=df.columns[0], color='r')
```

Comment: Thanks ,but I want to plot  label 1 and 0 in the same line